# Subscript for Norms are too high

Tags: subscripts

I'm defining `\norm` by `\|#\|`. However, when I type `\norm{x}_{M}`, the M comes out at exactly the same height as if one typed `x_M`. The problem is really noticeable with upper-case subscripts. Is there a way to modify the `\norm` definition so that the subscript M is lowered slightly below `\|` and truly appears as its subscript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to define it yourself, it is better with the help of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
$\norm{x}_Mx_M$
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Is there a variable that sets how high/low a subscript is placed?

Comment: @Chrystomath Not that I know

Comment: @karlkoeller Can it be done without mathtools and/or pairedDelimiter? Because those don't work for me.

Comment: The MWE does not work for me (MiKTeX, mathtools 1.29): both subscripts are the same height.

Answer (score 3):

I hate re-inventing (Because I am lazy). With `physics` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  \[
  a\norm{x}_{M}a
  \]
  \[
  a\abs{x}_{M}a
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to meet you. I'm a mathematician.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|} 

a$\norm{x}_Mx_M$a
```

[image]