# Adjustable norm to subscript and superscript(no mathtools package)

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

I would like to achieve something very similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154398/subscript-for-norms-are-too-high) but without using `mathtools`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\norm#1{\lVert{#1}\rVert}
\begin{document}
Euclidean norm squared looks ugly. See $\norm{x}_2^2$
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I would like the superscript to go higher and the subscript to go lower, while making the line longer. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you have against mathtools? It is the indispensable complement of amsmath.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't use it when I started writing my document and if I added now that is 80 pages long it changes so many things that it increases the number of pages. Also, it doesn't actually fixes my problem(but that could be due to clashing definitions of the norm or something). That said, I could use if it was possible to isolate it in some way or just import the paired delimiter.